# ConnectionStringSetting for RabbitMqTrigger Azure Functions c#

Tags: c#, azure, rabbitmq, azure-functions

I'm trying to figure out what needs to go in ConnectionStringSetting of the RabbitMqTrigger.  There is a Microsoft document on this but it's no help because they have the ConnectionStringSetting value in appsetting.json file probably and what I need is the actual value and syntax of that value.
Microsoft Document [RabbitMQ trigger for Azure Functions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-rabbitmq-trigger?tabs=csharp).  My ConnectionFactory Looks like this `new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "10.00.11.22", VirtualHost = "/", Port = 5672, UserName = "user", Password = "password" }`
.  Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The RabbitMq connection string has many possible formats based on certain variations in the properties included in the value, but a widely used standard format looks like this:

```
"amqp://username:password@host:0000/vhost"
```

Here, `amqp` represents the AMQP connection protocol (the underlying Application Layer protocol on which RabbitMq message broker has been built), `username` is your username, `password` is your password, `host` is your RabbitMq host name, `0000` represents the Port Number on which your RabbitMq is running, and `vhost` is the name of your Virtual Host.

For more information on other variations, check out this link: [RabbitMq URI Specs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html)

Comment: I'm getting this error "RabbitMQ.Client: None of the specified endpoints were reachable".  Azure function is not in a container but RabbitMq is in a container in case that makes a difference.

Comment: This error could be due to hundreds of reasons. Were you able to get any detailed stack trace or something?